# Would this question be on topic? - Problem Replacing Cell Phone LCD

Tags: discussion

The Super User question guidelines say that questions related to computer hardware are on topic, so I would expect a problem replacing a smartphone's LCD and digitizer would be on topic, but the guidelines also say cell phone related questions are off topic, so even though this question would deal with hardware, would it still make the question off-topic?

From the guidlelines:

```
Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …

    computer hardware,
    computer software, or
    personal and home computer networking

and it is not about …

    programming and software development,
    video games or consoles,
    websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,
    electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,
    issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,
    asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation,

… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its off topic, as it says there.

Does it involve a cellphone? Yes.

Does it involve a computer? No.

Is a phone digitiser and screen *computer* hardware? Not really, well not in this context.

Tablets are a grey area, but I wouldn't think that a question of that sort fits the *intent* of the rules with respect to that.

So yes, its certainly off topic. I have no idea where on SE it would be on topic however.

Comment: Technically a cell phone is a computer, but I guess if it says specifically no cell phones, then it is off topic.

Comment: @JohnDoe - Technically the Apple Watch is a computer does not mean questions about the Apple Watch are on topic here at Superuser.

Answer (score 2):

It might be enough on topic at android to get an answer (before it is closed), as that group has many people highly skilled in messing with the phones, not so much hardware side of it, unless firmware counts, but there might be one person who has done replacements like that.

I have messed with resistive touch and digitisers many times,  minus some taped or adhesive or glued areas that can be confusing as to what to do, it is worth trying , even failing for any of them.  If a human could make it, if a human could fix it, your human :-) you have nothing to lose.

IMO it is still sad there is not a very Wide open unrestricted hardware Q&A for the stack exchange, the ones that do cover some sorts of hardware, start out thier Area51 with unnessisary restrictions, when a "All Computer Hardware" would take off like a rocket to the moon.